# How does byte code instrumentation improve performance?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I am new to JPA/Hibernate and want to understand:

- What is byte code instrumentation?
- How is it used in improving performance?

I tried to google that. but I was unable to comprehend it. It would be great if any one can explain it in laymen terms.

Comment: did you already read [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38080451/1248974) and its referred post [Java Bytecode Instrumentation: An Introduction](http://www.correlsense.com/java-bytecode-instrumentation-an-introduction/)?

Comment: Reformat question..