# Grails/GORM lazy loading of CLOB field

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm, lazy-loading, clob

I am trying to make one field of my Grails domain class to be lazily-loaded. In fact this is a CLOB column in DB, but it mapped to String field in Grails domain class.
So I've created following hibernate mapping for this class:

```
<hibernate-mapping>
<class name="MyClass" table="my_table">
    <id name="id" column="id">
        <generator  class="native"/>
    </id>       
    <property name="clobCol" type="materialized_clob" lazy="true"/>
    <property name="someOtherField" type="string"/>
</class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

My domain class looks like following:

```
class MyClass {

    String someOtherField

    String clobCol

    static constraints = {
        clobCol(nullable: true)
    }
}
```

I am expecting that `clobCol` should be lazy when I am querying DB using DetachedCriteria. But in fact it is being eagerly-loaded.
Is it possible to make field lazy in this way? If yes so what am I doing wrong? If no so what is the best way to make `clobCol` be lazy without lots of refactoring classes and existing queries?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can achieve this by declaring a property named fetchMode in your domain class that contains a map of property/fetch types

```
class MyClass {

    static fetchMode = [clobCol: 'lazy']

    ...
}
```

Comment: As I understand in GORM this works only for associations and not for fields. That's why I am trying to configure such behavior in hibernate mapping file, hibernate should have this ability.

Comment: @its.ok009 I see. Have you checked out this question and the links in the answer? Might be helpful. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11526255/lazy-fetching-single-column-class-attribute-with-hibernate

Comment: Yes, thanks Mike. I've already checked these notes on how it works in Java/Hibernate. Unfortunately I didn't find any information on how to turn on this 'bytecode instrumentation' in Grails, if it is possible