# Partly loading sub-entities that are attributes or collections

Tags: hibernate, jpa, lazy-loading

Let's say I have the following two entities:

```
@Entity
public class Pet
{
   private String name;
   private Integer age;
}

@Entity
public class Person
{
   @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
   private Pet pet;
   // and ten additional attributes
}
```

I often get entities that have many attributes, often also in collections, so one to many relations. But most of the time I need only one attribute to display when loading parent entity (Person in our case).

> So the idea is to not load whole sub-entities for single attribute and
>   to save performance.

Is it possible to load a `Person` and its `Pet` with only `name` without loading other 11 attributes with JPA or at least with Hibernate?

**EDIT:**

I've found some answers [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11526255/lazy-fetching-single-column-class-attribute-with-hibernate), which unfortunately does not solve my problem.

Any further input is welcome.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for a [@Basic(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/Basic.html) JPA field annotation.

However there's no guarantee that a particular persistence provider will follow this JPA recommendation.

> The LAZY strategy is a hint to the persistence provider runtime.

Alternatively you could extract your `Pet`'s lazy-loaded content into a separate entity and use `@OneToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)` annotation.

Comment: Which unfortunately is not supported by Hibernate... :(

Comment: You could consider the second option I have suggested, i.e. extracting your lazy data into a separate entity.